# Conditional logic in Makefile from Grep exit codes

Tags: makefile, exit-code

I'm writing a connivence function in a Makefile and I'm having some trouble capturing and making decisions returned by a `grep` status code.

I'm aware that a [command that exits with a non-zero status will terminate Make](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153763/dont-stop-makeing-if-a-command-fails-but-check-exit-status). And I also know that `make`, by default, spawns an `sh` shell, so I'm not sure if that's complicating things.

I'm running this command: `golint | grep -v "comment on exported"` which returns `1` if the command completes successfully (there is no output from `grep`; all output is filtered) and `0` if there is still output left unfiltered. Not sure why `grep` is counterintuitive this way, but that's besides the point.

I want to `echo 'No liniting issues'` on success and just print the unfiltered lines on failure.

I thought any one of these permutations would work:

```
lint:
        # Will never print 'No linting issues'
        ! golint | grep -v "comment on exported" || echo 'No linting issues'
        ! `golint | grep -v "comment on exported"` || echo 'No linting issues'
        ! (golint | grep -v "comment on exported") || echo 'No linting issues'

        # Exits with syntax error: unexpected end of file
        if [ $(golint | grep -v "comment on exported") -ne 0 ]; then
          echo 'No linting issues'
        fi
```

This seems to be such a simple thing, so this question is coming more out of frustration to get it to work than anything else.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: What is the output of `golint`? Can you replace `golint` with `echo ...` to simplify the example?

Comment: Yeah, `golint` is functionally equivalent to `echo 'comment on exported'`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error; your first permutation seems to work perfectly. Can you try the command on the command line, rather than in Make?